# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI: in a Spring MVC app

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm getting this error.

my **web.xml** has this

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/web-application-config.xml</param-value>
   </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>springweb</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/app/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have this in my web-application-config.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
       <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
</bean>

<bean name="/Scheduling.htm" class="com.web.SchedulingController"/>
```

my com.web.SchedulingController looks like this

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

package com.web; 

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller;


public class SchedulingController implements Controller{

public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/jsp/Scheduling_main.jsp");
    modelAndView.addObject("message","Hello World MVC!!");
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

When I hit this controller with the URL http://localhost:8080/project1/app/Scheduling.htm
The Scheduling_main.jsp gets displayed but the images are not displayed properly. Also the js and css file are not getting rendered.

I'm accessing the images like this

```
<img src="jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png" title="Save Appointment">
```

If I change the URL mapping in the servlet definition to *.htm, the images get displayed fine. Can you point out where I'm missing out.

Here is complete error message

```
WARN  [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mavenproject1/app/jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springweb'
```

Thanks a lot.
Ravi

Comment: Here is complete Error message:
WARN  [PageNotFound] No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mavenproject1/app/jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springweb'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm think it happens because you try get your image though servlet (mapped as /app/*) You need  get static content without handle it with your servlet, for example set image source to

`<img src="../jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png" title="Save Appointment">`

then real URI of your image will be /mavenproject1/jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png, and it will returned by your tomcat itself as is, without any processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. Just got to learn more about URL mappings.

Comment: saved my day. Would you mind explaining a little more. when I prefix the file path with '../' does it indirectly become absoultepath? and so that the handler is not invoked?

Comment: @kalyan No, ".." not mean to be absolute path, ".." mean goto upper directory. So what actually happens: when you set image src to ../jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png your full path will be  /mavenproject1/app/../jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png and will be transform to /mavenproject1/jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png by your browser. But your servet handles only /mavenproject1/app/* urls, so /mavenproject1/jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png will be handlet by tomcat itself and returned as is, as usual static content. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: I got your point. This way it just avoids the handler url path. But when I access the jsp page statically and not through the view rendering, i still get the images correctly. So the link  ../jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png should become /mavenproject1/../jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png, how does this handled?

Comment: actually the same. /mavenproject1/../jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png becomes /jquerylib/images/save_32x32.png, so you run out of your webapp context (mavenproject1) , and this path will be handled by the ROOT web application

Comment: Awesome!!You saved my day!! I had been so much solutions with no effect!!

Answer (score 2):

I just add three rules before spring default rule (/**) to tuckey's urlrewritefilter (urlrewrite.xml) to solve the problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 3.0//EN" "http://tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite3.0.dtd">
    <urlrewrite default-match-type="wildcard">
        <rule>
            <from>/</from>
            <to>/app/welcome</to>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <from>/scripts/**</from>
            <to>/scripts/$1</to>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <from>/styles/**</from>
            <to>/styles/$1</to>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <from>/images/**</from>
            <to>/images/$1</to>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <from>/**</from>
            <to>/app/$1</to>
        </rule>
        <outbound-rule>
            <from>/app/**</from>
            <to>/$1</to>
        </outbound-rule>    
    </urlrewrite>
```

[How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something/3614036#3614036)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to springweb-servlet.xml

`<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>`

Below text is extracted from [Spring reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources)

> This tag allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (thus overriding the mapping of the container's default Servlet), while still allowing static resource requests to be handled by the container's default Servlet. It configures a DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler with a URL mapping (given a lowest precedence order) of "/**". This handler will forward all requests to the default Servlet.