# Can I exclude some concrete urls from <url-pattern> inside <filter-mapping>?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I want some concrete filter to be applied for all urls except for one concrete (i.e. for `/*` except for `/specialpath`).

Is there a possibility to do that?

---

sample code:

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.somproject.AFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SomeFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>   <!-- the question is: how to modify this line?  -->
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 172, accepted):

The standard Servlet API doesn't support this facility. You may want either to use a rewrite-URL filter for this like [Tuckey's one](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) (which is much similar Apache HTTPD's `mod_rewrite`), or to add a check in the `doFilter()` method of the Filter listening on `/*`.

```
String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
if (path.startsWith("/specialpath/")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue chain.
} else {
    // Do your business stuff here for all paths other than /specialpath.
}
```

You can if necessary specify the paths-to-be-ignored as an `init-param` of the filter so that you can control it in the `web.xml` anyway. You can get it in the filter as follows:

```
private String pathToBeIgnored;

public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    pathToBeIgnored = config.getInitParameter("pathToBeIgnored");
}
```

If the filter is part of 3rd party API and thus you can't modify it, then map it on a more specific `url-pattern`, e.g. `/otherfilterpath/*` and create a new filter on `/*` which forwards to the path matching the 3rd party filter.

```
String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
if (path.startsWith("/specialpath/")) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response); // Just continue chain.
} else {
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/otherfilterpath" + path).forward(request, response);
}
```

To avoid that this filter will call itself in an infinite loop you need to let it listen (dispatch) on `REQUEST` only and the 3rd party filter on `FORWARD` only.

#### See also:

- [How to prevent static resources from being handled by front controller servlet which is mapped on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13521946/how-to-prevent-static-resources-from-being-handled-by-front-controller-servlet-w)
- [How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something)

Comment: My problem is that the filter is not mine, it's from component library.

Comment: Ypu should take the compnent library filter and extend it in order to add the code you want to use to perform the exclusions.

Comment: @BalusC If the "/specialpath" just serves a static resource like js, css etc, does chain.doFilter() make the response slower? Is there a method to serve the resource directly without chaining the filter?

Comment: @BenhurCD: I have really no idea how you could ever come up to this performance concern.

Answer (score 15):

I used an approach [described by Eric Daugherty](http://blog.ericdaugherty.com/2010/02/excluding-content-from-url-pattern-in.html): I created a special servlet that always answers with 403 code and put its mapping before the general one.

Mapping fragment:

```xml
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>generalServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>project.servlet.GeneralServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>specialServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>project.servlet.SpecialServlet</servlet-class>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>specialServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/restricted/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>generalServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

And the servlet class:

```
public class SpecialServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public SpecialServlet() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    }
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

This approach works when you want to prevent a certain filter and all the following ones. It should work well if you eg. want to serve some content as static resources within your servlet container instead of letting your application logic (through a filter like GuiceFilter):

Map the folder with your static resource files to the default servlet. Create a servlet filter and put it *before* the GuiceFilter in your web.xml. In your created filter, you can separate between forwarding some requests to the GuiceFilter and others directly to the dispatcher. Example follows...

**web.xml**

```xml
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>StaticResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.project.filter.StaticResourceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StaticResourceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**StaticResourceFilter.class**

```
public class StaticResourceFilter implements Filter {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StaticResourceFilter.class);

    private static final String RESOURCE_PATH = "/static/";
    @Override
    public void init(final FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        LOGGER.info("StaticResourceFilter initialized");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response,
                         final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath();
        if (path.toLowerCase().startsWith(RESOURCE_PATH)) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        LOGGER.info("StaticResourceFilter destroyed");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately if you just want to skip a single step in the filter chain while keeping those that follows, this will not work.

Comment: I tried to go with your solution, but for the files that I apply the filter and break the chain,  I get the followin error; Uncaught exception thrown by filter Static Resource Filter: java.io.FileNotFoundException.  Any idea why ?

Comment: In multi-context setups, using `.getRequestURI()` will break (causing a 404 most likely) because `.getRequestDispatcher` resolves _relative to the context path_. If your context path is `/a`, then in your example the request URI would be `/a/static`, and using `getRequestDispatcher("/a/static")` will cause it to resolve against `/a/a/static` instead. Fix: use `.getServletPath()` instead of `.getRequestURI()`. I'll submit an edit to fix this, but just wanted to leave a comment FYI

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can, the only other configuration alternative is to enumerate the paths that you want to be filtered, so instead of `/*` you could add some for `/this/*` and `/that/*` etc, but that won't lead to a sufficient solution when you have alot of those paths.

What you can do is add a parameter to the filter providing an expression (like a regular expression) which is used to skip the filter functionality for the paths matched.
The servlet container will still call your filter for those url's but you will have better control over the configuration.

**Edit**

Now that you mention you have no control over the filter, what you could do is either inherit from that filter calling `super` methods in its methods except when the url path you want to skip is present and follow the filter chain like @BalusC proposed, or build a filter which instantiates your filter and delegates under the same circumstances. In both cases the filter parameters would include both the expression parameter you add and those of the filter you inherit from or delegate to.

The advantage of building a delegating filter (a wrapper) is that you can add the filter class of the wrapped filter as parameter and reuse it in other situations like this one.

Answer (score 3):

I also Had to filter based on the URL pattern(/{servicename}/api/stats/)in java code .

```
if (path.startsWith("/{servicename}/api/statistics/")) {
validatingAuthToken(((HttpServletRequest) request).getHeader("auth_token"));
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);            
}
```

But its bizarre, that servlet doesn't support url pattern other than (/*), This should be a very common case for servlet API's !

Answer (score 0):

I have encounterd the same issue, but I find a anwser showing below.

web.xml

```
 <!-- set this param value for the filter-->
    <init-param>
            <param-name>freePages</param-name>
            <param-value>
            MainFrame.jsp;
            </param-value>
    </init-param>
```

filter.java

```
strFreePages = config.getInitParameter("freePages"); //get the exclue pattern from config file
isFreePage(strRequestPage)  //decide the exclude path
```

this way you don't have to harass the concrete Filter class.

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you cannot change the original filter mapping ("/*" in my case)  and you are dispatching to an unchangeable third-party filter, you can find useful the following:

- Intercept the path to be bypassed
- Skip to and execute the last ring of the filter chain (the servlet itself)
- The skipping is done via reflection, inspecting the container instances in debug mode

The following works in Weblogic 12.1.3:

> ```
>       import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.FieldUtils;
>       import javax.servlet.Filter;
>
>       [...]
>
>       @Override   
>       public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletRespons response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException { 
>           String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
>
>           if(!bypassSWA(path)){
>               swpFilterHandler.doFilter(request, response, chain);
>
>           } else {
>               try {
>                   ((Filter) (FieldUtils.readField(
>                                 (FieldUtils.readField(
>                                         (FieldUtils.readField(chain, "filters", true)), "last", true)), "item", true)))
>                   .doFilter(request, response, chain);
>               } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
>                   e.printStackTrace();
>               }           
>           }   
>       }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle this in Spring 2 as following

```
 private boolean isInPath(ServletRequest request) {
   String PATH_TO_VALIDATE = "/path/";
   String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
   return path != null && path.toLowerCase().contains(PATH_TO_VALIDATE);
}
```