# In a web.xml url-pattern matcher is there a way to exclude URLs?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, servlet-filters

I wrote a filter that needs to be invoked every time a url on my site is accessed EXCEPT the CSS, JS, and IMAGE files.  So in my  definition I'd like to have something like:

```
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>myAuthorizationFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>NOT /css && NOT /js && NOT /images</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is there anyway to do this?  The only documentation I can find has only /*

**UPDATE:**

I ended up using something similar to an answer provided by Mr.J4mes:

```
   private static Pattern excludeUrls = Pattern.compile("^.*/(css|js|images)/.*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
   private boolean isWorthyRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
       String url = request.getRequestURI().toString();
       Matcher m = excludeUrls.matcher(url);

       return (!m.matches());
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I exclude some concrete urls from <url-pattern> inside <filter-mapping>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you can try this one:

```
@WebFilter(filterName = "myFilter", urlPatterns = {"*.xhtml"})
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

   @Override
   public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
      String path = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getServletPath();

      if (excludeFromFilter(path)) chain.doFilter(request, response);
      else // do something
   }

   private boolean excludeFromFilter(String path) {
      if (path.startsWith("/javax.faces.resource")) return true; // add more page to exclude here
      else return false;
   }
}
```

Comment: where is @WebFilter from?  I'm currently using spring-mvc and I'm defining my filter using @Service(value="myAuthorizationFilter")

Comment: I think this one is a normal JavaEE annotation. Check out [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebFilter.html)

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this but I used regex's with Pattern and Matcher.  
Like this:
`private static Pattern excludeUrls = Pattern.compile("^.*/(css|js|images|ckeditor)/.*$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Comment: :P Then you should update your question with how you succeeded to do so and you can mark this one as an answer too =P.

Answer (score 6):

The URL pattern mapping does not support exclusions. This is a limitation of the Servlet specification. You can try the manual workaround posted by Mr.J4mes.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you could declare another "blank" filter for `css`, `js` etc, and put it before others filter mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I used the security-constraint to access control. See the code:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Unsecured resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

I follow [this](http://blog.brunoraljic.com/how-to-exclude-css-and-js-files-from-spring-mvc-dispatcher-mapping/) tutorial.