# Application Security Not loading resources

Tags: java, web-applications, web.xml, http-authentication

I am developing a Java Web app. 
I have just added a filter in order to make sure that users have logged in.

I added in my web.xml file:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>security-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.controllers.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>security-filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

When I load the pages none of the resources load ie, images, css etc.

The error says:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
3http://localhost:8080/resources/js/login Failed to load resource: net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

But if i remove the filter from the web.xml everything is fine.

In my .jsp file I also have the following:

```
<link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

Comment: you are using .jsp files? can you show how you load css/images in your jsp/html files?

Comment: at the top i have:
<link href="/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<img src="/resources/images/logo.png"

Comment: the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658949/in-a-web-xml-url-pattern-matcher-is-there-a-way-to-exclude-urls?noredirect=1&lq=1) may help