# Setting X-Content-Type-Options response header corrupts the PNG file

Tags: java, security, xss, response-headers

I want to get the clarity on these headers in my application:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "frame-ancestors 'self'");    
response.setHeader("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff"); 
response.setHeader("X-XSS-Protection", "1; mode=block"); 
response.setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=7776000; cludeSubdomains");
String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getContextPath();
response.setHeader("SET-COOKIE", "JSESSIONID=" +
    ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession().getId() +
    ";Path="+contextPath+";Secure;HttpOnly");
response.setHeader("Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store,max-age=0, must-revalidate");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
response.setHeader("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
```

As of now I know:

1. Content Security Policy is an added layer of security that helps to
   detect and mitigate certain types of attacks, including Cross Site
   Scripting (XSS) and data injection attacks.
2. X-Content-Type-Options response HTTP header is a marker used by the server to indicate that the [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types) advertised in the Content-Type headers should not be changed and be followed.
3. [X-XSS-protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090577/what-is-the-http-header-x-xss-protection) is XSS Filter.
4. Strict-Transport-Security is an opt-in security enhancement that is specified by a web application through the use of a special response header. Once a supported browser receives this header that browser will prevent any communications from being sent over HTTP to the specified domain and will instead send all communications over HTTPS.
5. Cache-control general-header field is used to specify directives for caching mechanisms in both, requests and responses.
6. Pragma meant to prevent the client from caching the response. However there is a difference between Cache control and Pragma response headers as they both does same work except Pragma is the HTTP/1.0 implementation and cache-control is the HTTP/1.1 implementation of the same concept..
7. X-Frame-Options used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a `frame`, `iframe` or `object`.

Now I have this code in CrossSiteScriptingFilter which is mapped in `web.xml` which does XSS filtering. but as a result it changes the `.png` files encoding and remove the `?`characters which corrupt PNG file encoding and thus giving false PNG data.

Please check the screenshot, it has no `?` characters and are replaced by empty string and as a result it does not allow `.png` files to render. [image]

I analysed the code and found that removing response header `X-Content-Type-Options` is doing the job (`.png` files are rendering properly).

I am still not sure why this problem occurs and  why `X-Content-Type-Options` was replacing the `?` character to `""` string which was creating the problem. Can somebody explain.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you're pretty close to your answer: XSS filtering of special characters is a bad idea with binary files which may validly use characters that would be out of place in (x)html, js, or similar interpreted files.

Normally, web apps split such resources into their own directory that will have a different process applied to its contents, say, not running an XSS protection filter over it. When you configure the filter, you should exclude paths known to exclusively contain binary data, such as the aforementioned resource directories.

What seems likely is that the headers are causing/prohibiting the filter from guessing at the MIME-type, misinterpreting your binary as html or similar (probably based on the text in the PNG header) or just falling back on the filter by default, and then sanitising it. It could be that your MIME-type headers are wrong and the sniffer is fixing it (hence telling it not to do so prevents it from recovering).

Comment: +1 for answer, is there any option in web.xml to exclude known paths for XSS scripting. For now I have a fix I was checking the path in my filter before proceeding with the response headers. If there is any other solution which I can think of other than it I'd be happy to know it.

Comment: I'm not sure there is without getting complicated. This question seems relevant and they came to a similar conclusion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658949/in-a-web-xml-url-pattern-matcher-is-there-a-way-to-exclude-urls but the accepted answer resorts to code.