# How to prevent static resources from being handled by front controller servlet which is mapped on /*

Tags: servlets

I have a servlet which acts as a front controller.

```
@WebServlet("/*")
```

However, this also handles CSS and image files. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. Use a more specific URL pattern such as `/app/*` or `*.do` and then let all your page requests match this URL pattern. See also [Design Patterns web based applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/3542297#3542297)
2. The same as 1, but you want to hide the servlet mapping from the request URL; you should then put all static resources in a common folder such as `/static` or `/resources` and create a filter which checks if the request URL doesn't match it and then forward to the servlet. Here's an example which assumes that your controller servlet is a `@WebServlet("/app/*")` and that the filter is a `@WebFilter("/*")` and that all your static resources are in `/resources` folder.

   ```
   HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
   String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getContextPath().length());

   if (path.startsWith("/resources/")) {
       chain.doFilter(request, response); // Goes to default servlet.
   } else {
       request.getRequestDispatcher("/app" + path).forward(request, response); // Goes to your controller.
   }
   ```

   See also [How to access static resources when mapping a global front controller servlet on /*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870150/how-to-access-static-resources-when-using-default-servlet/3593513#3593513).

Comment: @BalusC why do static resource throw 404 when loaded via controller.
I had a filter mapped with /*. While loaded jquery file it throws and error 404 - resource not found.
I resolved it by using the solution you have provided above.
Can you please clear my doubts ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question and I guess @BalusC 's answer probably works fine. But I couldn't modify the URL for the JSF app am working on, so I simply just check for the path and return if it is to static resources:

```
    String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
    if (path.contains("/resources/")) {
        return;
    }
```

This works fine for me.