# Spring MVC RequestMapping PathVariable in the first place

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I would like to set for each user's own profile link.
Like this:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/{userlogin}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String page(@PathVariable("userlogin") String userlogin, ModelMap model) {
        System.out.println(userlogin);
        return "user";
    }
```

But static pages get this expression too..
Like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String hello() {
    System.out.println("hello mapping");
    return "hello";
}
```

That is when I request GET request "hello" that calls both controllers.
I would like to do that, user controller calls only if other methods not called.

Console, when I calls *localhost:8080/123:*

```
123
```

Console, when I calls *localhost:8080/hello:*

```
hello 
hello mapping
```

or

```
hello mapping
hello
```

I want to get only

```
hello mapping
```

when calls *localhost:8080/hello*

Who knows how it can be implemented?

Comment: Just call one method with path variable with it
i.e. requestMapping(value="/hello/{userLogin}")

Comment: Thank you for response. But it not what i want.. I changed the post to a more intuitive

Comment: I advise to look in the direction of filters, which will redirect to other path for localhost:8080/hello and how result to other controller. For example, you may look this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC can use URI Template Patterns with Regular Expressions. Provided :

- `userlogin` only contain digits
- others URL immediately under root contains at least one non digit character

you can use that in your `@RequestMapping` :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userlogin:\\d+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String page(@PathVariable("userlogin") String userlogin, ModelMap model) {
    //...
}
```

If the separation between `userlogin` and other URL is different from what I imagined, it can be easy to adapt.