# Exclude particular URL in servlet filter

Tags: url, servlets, web.xml, servlet-filters

How to exclude particular format of URL from the filter?

Is there a standard method or alternative solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I exclude some concrete urls from <url-pattern> inside <filter-mapping>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't possible via `<url-pattern>` configuration.

You've basically 2 options:

1. Make `<url-pattern>` more specific. E.g. move all those resources wich really need to be filtered in a specific folder like `/app` and set the `<url-pattern>` to `/app/*`. Then you can just put the excluded page outside that folder.
2. Check for the request URI in the filter and just continue the chain if it represents the excluded page.

   E.g.

   ```
   String loginURL = request.getContextPath() + "/login.jsp";

   if (request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL)) {
       chain.doFilter(request, response);
   }
   else {
       // ...
   }
   ```