# Exclude url from basicAuthenticationFilter

Tags: java, filter, jersey, web.xml

I want to exclude one url from filter mapping, is it possible to do that in web.xml?

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>basicAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported> 
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>basicAuthenticationFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

The url I want to exclude is something like `/health`.

If that is not possible, is there any example in java code about how we can do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I exclude some concrete urls from <url-pattern> inside <filter-mapping>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping)

Comment: @victor I tried different approached mentioned on internet but none of them worked.I have edited my question also, to get better understanding.