# too many redirects using filter class

Tags: jsf, servlet-filters

JSF 2.2 and Primefaces 6.0

I'm trying to use filter class for authentication session control. But filter class running 21 times and browser set error message ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>maintenancemonitoring</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>view.filters.AuthenticationFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>cupertino</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Filter class :

```
public void
        doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,
                                                                                                         ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    System.out.println("aaaaa");

    String currentLoginId = null;
    if(session.getAttribute("currentLoginId")!=null){
        currentLoginId = (String) session.getAttribute("currentLoginId");
    }

    if(currentLoginId != null){
        setResponseHeaders(response);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
    }
}

private void setResponseHeaders(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    httpResponse.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
    httpResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    httpResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
    httpResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "post-check=0");
    httpResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "pre-check=0");
    httpResponse.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
    httpResponse.addDateHeader("Expires", 0);
}
```

Login action in loginBean:

```
public String actionLogin(ActionEvent actionEvent) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) getExternalContext().getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) getExternalContext().getResponse();

    AuthUser user = getValidUser();

    request.setAttribute("user", user);

    if (user == null) {
        addMessage("Kullanıcı adı ya da şifre hatalı");
        return null;
    }

    return handleUserLogin(user, request, response);
}
```

Create session in loginHandler class:

```
private String createNewSessionAndRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthUser user) {
    HttpSession session = getSessionForRequest(request);

    session.setAttribute("currentLoginId", user.getUserName());

    if (request.isRequestedSessionIdValid() && session != null && session.getAttribute("currentLoginId") != null) {
        try {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/faces/welcome.xhtml");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return "/welcome.xhtml";
}
```

Comment: You should check since the redirection `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");` match the filter, if this is not doing a recursive call.

Comment: I corrected the tagging in ypur question. Please tag it better next time

Comment: Note : You should add the Stacktrace when you get an exceptino

Comment: @AxelH I checked redirection url and url is true

Comment: @EmreArslan I don't understand your last statement... _url is true_ ?

Answer (score 5):

The reason I see for this error is a recursive call.

Since you are filtering every `.xthml` page and in the filter you are redirecting to

```
response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/faces/login.xhtml");
```

You are filtrering this redirection itself. You should forward the request instead since you have set the filtrer to work on `REQUEST` but not on `FORWARD`.

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

The forward looks like this (not exactly, didn't remember the exact code in a filter...) :

```
ServletContext.getRequestDispatcher("/faces/welcome.xhtml").forward()
```

A forward will only be filter if you add `<dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>` to the filter-mapping

Comment: Also have a look at this post on how to exclude certain urls from beeing redirected (filtered): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping

Comment: @dognose indeed, without enough information, I simply didn't think about a more general exclusion. This is a different answer I believe.