# Why does servlet API not provide provision for exclusion patterns for filters?

Tags: java, servlet-filters, servlet-3.0

Servlet API provides the option to map your filter to specific URL patterns. They do not have an option to `exclude` specific patterns.

Spring provides this using [OncePerRequestFilter#shouldNotFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html#shouldNotFilter-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-)

Is there a specific reason behind the decision taken by them or is it done to avoid confusion regarding conflicting exclude/include patterns? I think that could be easily resolved by giving preference to `exclude` perhaps.

Would like to understand the reason for not having such a useful feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I exclude some concrete urls from <url-pattern> inside <filter-mapping>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping)

Comment: I saw the solutions and I am using the same solution. I just want to understand the reason behind not having this feature.