# How to declare Servlet on root path without overriding Spring MVC Controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, servlets

I have Spring Boot application with REST API mapped on `/api`. I need to define additional servlet on `/`. I want all request that match `/api` was handled by REST API and all others requests by the servlet. How to do this?

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class ApiController {

        @GetMapping
        public String get() {
            return "api";
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean customServletBean() {
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new HttpServlet() {
            @Override
            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
                resp.getWriter().println("custom");
            }
        }, "/*");
    }   
}
```

In code above I want something like this:

```
curl  http://localhost:8080/api/                                                                                                                           
> api⏎       
curl  http://localhost:8080/custom/
> custom
```

I have tried with filter to redirect requests, but all requests go to custom servlet:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean apiResolverFilter() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
    registrationBean.setFilter((req, response, chain) -> {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String path = request.getRequestURI().substring(request.getContextPath().length());
        if (path.startsWith("/api/")) {
            request.getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    });
    registrationBean.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

This project is available on github: https://github.com/mariuszs/nestedweb

Comment: Have a look at this thread <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125296/can-i-exclude-some-concrete-urls-from-url-pattern-inside-filter-mapping>

Comment: @Gro I have tried and this does not work (or I don't know how to use this)

Comment: That won't work. The `DispatcherServlet` is mapped to `/` registering another one will destroy the `DispatcherServlet`. Why does it need to be a servlet, why not just a regular controller? What is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @M.Deinum I need to use existing servlet from an external library (GitHttpServlet)

Comment: And why does it need to be mapped to `/`? You can also wrap that servlet in a ``

Comment: @M.Deinum This was my business requirements. I just want to know if this is possible.

Comment: Not without destroying the `DispatcherServlet`. You can try a [`ServletWrappingController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html) so it sits behind the `DispatcherServlet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When mapping a servlet to the root path you will override the mapping for the `DispatcherServlet` which, by default, is mapped to `/`.

There are basically 3 solutions you could try

1. Map the `DispatcherServlet` to `/api` and modify the mappings in your controllers
2. Use a [`ServletForwardingController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletForwardingController.html) to forward the request to the configured but unmapped `Servlet`
3. Use a [`ServletWrappingController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/ServletWrappingController.html) to wrap a `Servlet` instance

Number 2 and 3 are almost the same, with this difference that with option 3 Spring also manages the `Servlet` instance whereas with option 2, the Servlet container manages the `Servlet`.

### Mapping `DispatcherServlet` to `/api`

Option 1 can be an option if all of your controllers are mapped under `/api`, if they aren't this isn't an option. In your `application.properties` you would set the `spring.mvc.servlet.path` to `/api`. Then you would configure your other `Servlet` like you did in your question.

### Use a `ServletForwardingController`

Spring provides a `ServletForwardingController` which will lookup a `Servlet` in the `ServletContext` given the name of the servlet and forward the request to it. You will still have to register the `Servlet` but prevent it from being mapped.

Next you would need a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to map the URLs to this controller or set it as the default handler (basically a catch all).

```
@Bean
public ServletForwardingController forwarder() {
   ServletForwardingController controller = new ServletForwardingController();
   controller.setServletName("my-servlet");
   return controller;
}

@Bean
public CustomServlet customServlet() {
    return new CustomServlet();
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean customServletRegistration() {
    ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(customServlet(), false);
    registration.setServletName("customServlet");
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setDefaultHandler(forwarder());
    mapping.setOrder(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE  - 2);
    return mapping;
}
```

### Use a `ServletWrappingController`

Spring provides a `ServletWrappingController` which will internally create and configure a `Servlet` instance. It acts as an adapter from/to the `Servlet` to a Spring `Controller`. You don't have to register the `CustomServlet` in this case and is thus slightly easier to configure the then `ServletForwardingController`.

Next you would need a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to map the URLs to this controller or set it as the default handler (basically a catch all).

```
@Bean
public ServletWrappingController wrapper() {
   ServletWrappingController  controller = new ServletWrappingController ();
   controller.setServletName("my-servlet");
   controller.setServletClass(CustomerServlet.class);
   return controller;
}

@Bean
public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping() {
    SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
    mapping.setDefaultHandler(wrapper());
    mapping.setOrder(LOWEST_PRECEDENCE  - 2);
    return mapping;
}
```

Depending on your architecture and url structure you might want to go for option 1 or option 3.