# static resource mapping in spring mvc

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, static-resource

I did mapping for image files in spring context file as below:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/" />
```

I tested this for direct accessing of image in url in browser address bar:
       hhttp://host:port/ManageDepartments/images/oracle.PNG

It renders the requested image on browser but why it's preventing spring controller url for serving user request. After url mapping for images in spring context file, when I try below url its returning 404 error.

```
http://host:port/ManageDepartments/department/
```

Not getting department home page after doing image mapping in context file!

For jsp, below is configuration in spring configuration file:

```
    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
```

Below is project structure:

[image]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

  <display-name>Spring With MongoDB Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.rislg" />

<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/WEB-INF/images/" />

<!-- Factory bean that creates the Mongo instance -->
<bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
    <property name="host" value="localhost" />
</bean>

<!-- MongoTemplate for connecting and quering the documents in the database -->
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="test" />
</bean>

<!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
<bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />


<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />    

</beans>
```

In console, I am not looking any error but In browser I am getting HTTP Status 404 when I hit hhttp://host:port/ManageDepartments/department/ which was working earlier for getting department home page.

Rgrds

Comment: show your web.xml and dispatcher . did you find any errors in the console >

Comment: @SanKrish Please find updated post!

Comment: I recently wrote an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26325525/3545273) about  a similar problem.

Comment: @SergeBallesta still not getting solution. either controllers are accessible via dispatcher servlet url pattern "\" or image is accessible if I make url mapping entry in spring configuration file!

Answer (score 0):

As I explain in [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26325525/3545273) there is no way to get a spring-mvc allow for serving resources directly under root **and** map root URL to a controller.

But in your use case, your resources are not directly under root, and it should be enough to map `DispatcherServlet` to `/*` instead of `/` in your `web.xml` file.