# how do you create 2 servlets within one web.xml file?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web

This is my code for one servlet in my web.xml file:

```
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>

        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
```

Can I just copy and paste and change certain values and use that again?

SECOND QUESTION (WHICH MAY HELP ANSWER THE FIRST)

currently when i deploy my application in glassfish with this url localhost/HelloSpring
I get a 404. However, when I add /home on the end like so: localhost/HelloSpring/home
it goes to the correct page. I can also add /index localhost/HelloSpring/index on the end and that works correctly too. So how can I load localhost/HelloSpring/home from startup rather than having to type it in manually and thus avoiding the 404 error?

NOTE: when changing the url pattern from / to /home in the servlet mappings, fixes the /home problem but then means /index will not work

So in summary, how can I load up localhost/home from deployment and then type in index into the url /index and display the correct page?

p.s. stackoverflow would not let me type in my full address links so assume where I have said localhost it contains the port :8080 directly after

Comment: i think it's your url pattern, i'm using something like this <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> to have all .html requests handled so you probably need to play with this. Off the top of my head i don't remember if /* is legal or not. just a general idea though

Comment: that's what I was working with before but I thought web applications look a bit neater without the .html extensions. I was hoping just to do it without the extensions. It is definitely possible as most websites do this. i had thought of /* too but there was no joy to be found there either

Answer (score 0):

Your servlet does not recognize automatically a home page. You have to tell it by either using your redirect page (you already include it in welcome-file-list), or map your controller that serves the home page to the root as well:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didnt like that. copied and pasted your line of code into mine and then tried the url pattern with both / and /home. It gave me the same results as before. this is the url that loads up from deployment http://localhost:8080/HelloSpring/ might it have something to do with that?

Comment: Can you post the controller that handles the /home request?

Comment: package service;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class WebController {

   @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String home() {
    return "home";
   }
 
   @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index() {
    return "index";
   }
   
 
}

Comment: sorry that looks very messy. reposted below without imports: @Controller
public class WebController {

   @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String home() {
    return "home";
   }
 
   @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String index() {
    return "index";
   }
}

Comment: Seems ok. Have you redeployed the app? btw you can re-edit your question next time you need to append code. Dont do it in comments.

Comment: my apologies. Yes I have redeployed and still no success in the root issue. shut down netbeans, cleaned and built again and still no luck annoyingly.

Comment: Look at the answer of Serge Ballesta. I forgot to mention that I always serve explicitly static resources using mvc:resources, so maybe that's what you need.

Comment: okay i'll have a look. just going back to one other thing for me to clarify. when i deploy and get this page http://localhost:8080/HelloSpring. how can i the value of HelloSpring? or can i not?

Comment: also can you explain what the first part: context-param, all the way down to the closing listener tag does?

Comment: With context-param you set the location of the application context file where your beans or other configuration is defined in case  you are using complementary configuration files to your servlet configuration. Take some time to look into the spring reference documentation if you intend to work with spring. It covers all these concepts very well.

Answer (score 0):

For first question, you can of course declare as many servlets as you want in the web.xml file, but I really cannot figure a use case for declaring more than one `DispatcherServlet`.

Your second question seems related to the problem of hitting root url in a Spring MVC application. I tried some time ago to post in SO what I found on the problem : [Match for root url and serving of static resources](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26325524/3545273)

Comment: so can i copy and paste all the code for my current servlet and then just rename things right?

Comment: Of course you can, but then you will have to worry which servlet will be hit by which request, and configure controllers accordingly