# Mapping Resources in dispatcher servlet (Resin Server)

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, resin

**This is my dispacter-servlet.xml file. When i deploy the project on resin pro 4.0.36 it loads my index page and the content BUT FAILS to load css files and images stored under the staticresources folder**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.dogears" />


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<import resource="classpath:beans.xml"/>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/staticresources/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

**Please can anyone tell me how to mapp my static resources folder, so that whenever the request is of the patter /resources/* it redirects the request to the static resources folder. the staticresources folder is in** *MyspringProject/src/main/webapps directory*.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325524/match-for-root-url-and-serving-of-static-resources

Comment: Try my answer. May it helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my solution. I had deployed my spring webapp in the webapps folder of the resin directory.

I realised that `<mvc:resource />` mapping tag **does not** work when you have deployed your spring app on **resin server** instead of **tomcat**.

Hence i solved this by first creating a war file of my project and then extracted the war file on the desktop and later placed all the contents from the war file in the *webapps/root* (and not webapps folder) folder of resin directory. and then from my index page i used JSTL TAG to include the external stylesheet.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url  value="/staticresources/externalcss.css"/>">

</head>
<body>
<h2 class="text_style">Hello World!</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

IT WORKS !!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to map your staticresources directory as a root directory. In Eclipse that would be a "Source Folder" and in IntelliJ a "Resources Root".

Refer to the following help docs depending on your IDE:

Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-wizard-source-folder.htm

IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your **project directory** structure is like

```
- src
    - main
      - webapp
        - resources
          - css
            - abc.css
          - images
            - xyz.jpg
```

& your `.html` or `.jsp` pages are located in the directory as below

```
- webapp
  - index.jsp
  - pages
    - welcome.jsp
```

then you can **add link to your resources** in **`index.jsp`** page with the URL **`BaseURL/index.jsp`**

```
<link href="resources/css/abc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  

<body>
    <img src="resources/images/xyz.jpg" alt="" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
</body>
```

& to **`welcome.jsp`** with URL **`BaseURL/pages/welcome.jsp`** as

```
<link href="../resources/css/abc.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 

<body>
    <img src="../resources/images/xyz.jpg" alt="" style="width:100px;height:100px" />
</body>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: the mvc:resource mapping only is not recognized. so when i call resources it doesnt refer to the static resources folder.

Comment: I didn't get exactly what u mean ? Can u elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Means that the even though i had mapped all the resource request to the static resources folder the resin server would not redirect the requests to the static resources folder.

Comment: And hence it would not load the css and js files