# Skipping view files/pages without going through Dispatcher Servlet?

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets, web-applications

I am using Spring MVC framework for writing a web application. The first step is to modify the web.xml to make entry for the dispatcher servlet.

The snippet of the web.xml which has this change:

```
<servlet>
      <servlet-name>MediumScaleProject</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MediumScaleProject</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have following questions:

1) Does this mean anything with respect to context root has to go through this servlet mapping? (assume context root for this web application is /contextroot)

2) I want to capture user details in userDetails.html; with the above arrangement it is not working, that is if I access like this: /contextroot/userDetails.html; it is giving HTTP 404 error. What is the best strategy for handling these kind of scenarios?

Comment: Could you post some code snippet of controller please?

Comment: No, I have not written any controller, this is just an .html page, which a user would request initially. Does this simple page access too needs to have all the request handling logic?

Comment: I think yes, or you can set this page to tag `welcome-file-list`, or you can configure another servlet to map this url.

Comment: I once wrote a [Q+A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26325524) on the possibility of serving static files in a Spring-MVC application. Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a project with the use of Spring MVC framework, you will need the Model, View and Controller.

1. yes everything will pass through
2. you better start to implement the MVC-idea