# SpringBoot Whitelabel Error Page Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I setup everythink, project is building without errors but when I'm trying to check results on website`(http://localhost:8080/webstoreapp)` it's showing:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Feb 27 12:05:16 GMT 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

```
package com.exovsky.webstoreapp;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class WebstoreappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(WebstoreappApplication.class, args);

    }

}

package com.exovsky.webstoreapp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Controller
 public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("greeting", "Witaj w sklepie internetowym!");
        model.addAttribute("tagline", "Wyjątkowym i jedynym sklepie 
                           internetowym");
        return "welcome";
     }
```

**POM.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.exovsky</groupId>
    <artifactId>webstoreapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>webstoreapp</name>
    <description>webapp project in springboot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.9</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.13.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Give us `application.properties` as well..

Comment: what happens when you hit just http://localhost:8080/ ?  ommit the webstoreapp

Comment: Tell us what you are expecting by just returning `welcome`?

Comment: Unsure whether it is or not related, but the root URL can be [special for SpringMVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26325524/3545273)

Comment: that supposed to return :
Witaj w sklepie internetowym!
Wyjątkowym i jedynym sklepie internetowym.
Im doing example from this book:Spring MVC: Beginner's Guide
That supposed to work coz I have done step by step what they were guiding to do...