# Spring MVC - include static files / javascript , css

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

I have created MVC application.

I want to include js or css file into jsp.

My static files ar under:

```
- webapp
        -js/jquery.js
        -WEB-INF|
                |
                 - jsp/*.jsp
```

My code to include jquery is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="js/jquery.js" />"></script>
```

and i cant load the js file into view.

I see the logs with info:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/pool/js/jquery.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

what means, that MVC try to map url to js file.

I think that there is something with my configuration, but i don't know what.

my web.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495571/spring-not-finding-resource-files-css-jsp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `DispatcherServlet` mapping to e.g:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Or some other not conflicting `url-pattern` like `*.htm` or `/controllers/*`. Remember that from now on all your controllers will be available only through this pattern.

Now it is intercepting everything in your web application, including `.js` files, images, etc.

The same thing with `hibernateFilter` - you don't really need an open Hibernate session when fetching `.js` files, don't you?

Comment: but, when i do this, my actual mapping is distroyed. After change my url: http://localhost:8080/pool/main doesn't work

Comment: One chenge - i've added another servlet-mapping with *.js

Answer (score 19):

add this to you confing and modify the location according to your need.

```
  <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/"/>
```

see this [How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1483063/1437586)

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the simple jsp core ?

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/bootstrap.css'/>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use spring JSTL tags to include external script files or style sheets.
First you should include the the taglib in JSP as follows.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
```

Then you can include extenal script file using,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<spring:url value="/js/jquery.js"/>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your answer. But in the style.css file declare url that relate to path of image.

--style.css--

```
.cwt-object0
{
    display: block;
    left: 2.62%;
    margin-left: -1px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 43px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    background-image: url('/resources/images/object0.png');
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

How to use tag `<spring:url></spring:url>` in style.css file to see in browser IE/Firefox

--jsp file ---

```
<link href="<spring:url value="/resources/style.css"/>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

add mvc:resources in your config file(***-servlet.xml), you can find it works

Answer (score 0):

I just followed [Mkyong Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/) to place css, js, jquery & image files. Its working for me.

In servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/assets/" />
```

In JSP , import tag library

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

and add like

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/custom.css'/>">
```