# Spring not finding resource files (css, jsp...)

Tags: javascript, css, spring, spring-mvc, resources

I'm using a jsp file as a model from a Controller and I want to use an css styles and js libraries

- Proyect

  - Webcontent
  - assets
  - WEB-INF

    - jsp

In web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

 </web-app>
```

In applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="main.mypack.controller" />



<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

And in my jsp file: href="/assets/css/jquery.mobile.fixedToolbar.polyfill.css"

Noy working, any help?

EDIT: I'm using 2.5 Spring version, and I have errors like: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MyProject/assets/js/jqm-project.js] in DispatcherServlet with name 'MyProject'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that your requests for CSS and JS files are going through Dispatcher Servlet, which is not correct. Hence Spring won't find the mapping for those files it will not load them.

You need to add the resourceHandler for your application in the applicationContext.xml file as follows. This configuration will bypass the requests for CSS and JS files from the Dispatcher Servlet.

```
<mvc:resources location="/assets/" mapping="/assets/**" />
```

Hope this helps you... Cheers.

Please put following code in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks, It works witch Spring 3.X, but I'm using 2.5, any solution for this version?

Answer (score 2):

Auto-solved:

This mapping is blocking everything, I change this:

```
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

For this (and I change my calls to "call.do"):

```
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>MyProject</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

And it works!

Comment: It's always advisable not to use a / as url mapping while using any framework like struts or spring. Always try to use a url as *.do or *.htm to avoid unnecessary blocking