# Frontend files does not found inside java project

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, staticresource

I have a java project a company send to me, I must use the REST services in this project.

I upload some files, but java only see the index.jsp file. I try to use even a index.html file, but it is not seen.

I need to import css and js files inside the html, but they are not found.

Do I need to specify what kind of files the browser can show? or something like this?

This is the web.xml code

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app id="WebApp_ID">
    <display-name>SRA</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

What can I do?

Comment: just to be sure, you know that's not a basic java project but for an java enterprise application server?

Comment: Is a basic java project, with some services.. it has the jar file and src folder

Comment: web.xml files are special config file for enterprise servers such as weblogic, tomcat, websphere, glassfish or jboss, are you using one of them?

Comment: How are you trying to access these files, are they pages too?

Comment: sorry, I misunderstand. it's a tomcat..

when I load `localhost:8080/SRA` it shows the index.jsp file. but if I rename to index.html, it returns 404

Comment: the files are other pages, and JS/CSS files

Comment: Create a Webcontent folder under SRA and create 2 more for your js files and css files like  :  SRA/Webcontent/JS, include these files in the html or jsp files in your project also.

Comment: I dont have any SRA folder.. it's the `webapp` folder. I have created a webcontent folder inside..

It still the same, if index.jsp is inside it finds it, but index.html, wont find

Comment: Other page or file. using index.jsp, I cannot import css or js in the same folder

Comment: Do I have to map the files somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add this to my web.xml file

```
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change index.html from being welcome page add this to your web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>[YourJsp.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Or you can forward the browser to your page from your html by adding this to your head tag:

> < meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=menu.jsp" / >

For the js and css , include the css and js files in your jsp, taking into consideration the folder structure of your project:

css:

> < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/login.css"/ >

js:

> < script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jsfiles/index.js">

Comment: it's `<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/login.css" />` assets is a folder in the same level that the jsp, but it's not found

Comment: @Pablo  Put the assets folder outside at the same level as WEB-INF

Comment: Now it does not throw 404, but the files are empty

Comment: following this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10495571/spring-not-finding-resource-files-css-jsp I make the css/js work! how should I make the same for html?