# how to access image folder in spring application

Tags: java, spring

I like to access an image from the `web/images` directory. I like to access this image in the `spring controller`, so I can convert this image to `byte[]`. I am creating a chart and this image is part of the chart display. So, I am using this `byte[]` to construct `Graphic2d object`. Closest I have got to it is using this:

```
FileSystemResource resource = new FileSystemResource("images/"+imageName);
```

Currently, I have stored this image in the package structure. I like to do better than this. I like to read directly from `web/images` directory. Please give me some advice, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The more elegant way is let your controller implement `ServletContextAware` so as your controller can injecte `ServletContext` instance, then you should use:

```
InputStream  stream = servletContext.getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg");
int bytesRead;
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer, 0, 8192)) != -1) {
        //process image data, i.e. write to sompe place,etc.
}
//close the stream
stream.close();
```

BTW, as for servletContext.getRealPath, different servlet container might have different implementation, and it might not work after project packaged to a war file. so, it's recommended to use getResourceAsStream.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use `servlet context` to get the path to `web/images`. Use following code:

```
File file=new File(request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("images/file.jpg"));
```

Note: Here I am utilizing `request` i.e. `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: `getRealPath` is not portable

Comment: is the image being generated ? If not you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8582577/spring-mvc-include-static-files-javascript-css/11097442#11097442 . It can be used even if the image is generated but you have to know its name.