# Spring 3 doesn't return css

Tags: css, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I just started with Spring 3 MVC today. Running into a dilemma...
web.xml maps everything ("/") to Spring. But as a result, when I put something like:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/navigation.css" />`

It is not returned by the container...

Perhaps someone could suggest how to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mvc:resources`, as explained in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources). This allows service static resources from the web app, but also from the classpath.

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to serve it?  If you are trying to serve it from the webapp itself (ie WEB-INF/static/css) You would need to include a servlet to do that for you.  In the spring context you can include something like

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

You can see more here

[How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, use [`mvc:resource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-static-resources) to serve your static resources.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

It is also recommended to avoid using scriptlets in your JSP code if possible. You should instead use JSTL to build the correct path to your CSS file.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/resources/css/navigation.css" />"/>
```