# Displaying image in jsp

Tags: java, image, jsp

I have these folders in my project:

```
Spring3MVC
> img
   > logo.png
> src
   > main
      > webapp
         > WEB-INF
            > pages
               > login.jsp

...
```

I want display `logo.png` in my .jsp file.

I tried:

```
<img src="../img/logo.png">
<img src="./img/logo.png">
<img src="img/logo.png">
<img src="*/img/logo.png">
<img src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/logo.png"/>
```

But the result is:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/img/logo.png] in   DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
mar 15, 2012 12:24:48 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/*/img/logo.png] in   DispatcherServlet with name 'mvc-dispatcher'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your image in your webapp? What path is it in?

Comment: check out the answer from Joris in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something

Comment: when i doing everything like in link above, after add " <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />" i cant load any page even login - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringMVC/login]

Answer (score 0):

because the "img" directory should be under src/main/webapp

Whatever IDE you're using to deploy your app (or build software which is packaging it probably doesn't have any idea about your "img" directory.  It will simply do this:

```
1.  Copy all your classes into <deploy>/WEB-INF/class
2.  Copy all your dependencies into <deploy>/WEB-INF/lib
3.  Copy all resources from src/main/webapp into <deploy>
4.  Copy your defined web.xml into <deploy>/WEB-INF
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and resolved it by placing images in the server's directory structure as opposed to the portlet's. I'm using `apache-tomcat` and have it downloaded under:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.25\
```

In it there is a folder called "webapps" and I created a subfolder for my images there:

```
C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.25\webapps\portal_content\img
```

From the portlet JSP (i.e. `view.jsp`) I reference the image as such:

```
<"img src="/portal_content/img/my_image.gif">
```