# How to Serve static contents in Spring Container independent way?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, handlers

How to Serve static contents in Spring Container independent way

I can't use `<mvc:resources../>`

Eager to hear soon...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [nginx](http://nginx.org/) if you cant use Springs `ResourceHttpRequestHandler`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible methods mentioned in the answers to this SO question:

[Spring MVC 3 and handling static content - am I missing something?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something)