# Spring web app not starting in jetty server

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc, jetty

I've got a simple spring web app project developed using eclipse IDE. When I run the project using a jetty server, the server starts. Then I try to go to the context using the details, it says the following error of 404.

[image]

This is my web.xml file where I defined the starting screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>TouchPOS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>layout.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And this is the project resources.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? There is no exceptions while starting the server. Please help me!

I viewed the console and the following error was given! How can I resolve this!

```
    WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/TouchPOSApplication/layout.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
Apr 19, 2013 10:53:48 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
```

mvc-config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
</beans>
```

Comment: What does your `mvc-config` and controller look like?

Comment: Try using `<mvc:resources/>` and check , for more : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-static-resources

Comment: I've updated with the mvc-config file!

Comment: I agree with @NoobUnChained. It's probably a static resources problem. Your servlet url pattern "collides" with your static `layout.html` file.

Comment: how can I fix the issue! I replaced the *.html with / and still no luck!

Comment: Add `<mvc:resources mapping="..." location="..."/>` in your Spring context file . For more refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your application runs in the webapp context path you expect it to run? What's the name of your war file and did you provide a jetty context.xml file for that webapp where you configure the context path?

If not, then try using the name of the war file as context path:

e.g.:

if the name of the war is "webapps/touchpos.war" try `"http://localhost:8080/touchpos/"`.