# HTML page and Spring

Tags: html, spring, spring-mvc

I create Simple MVC project in Spring. Defaultr generic a jsp pages. I try change jsp to html and i:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

replace this:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</beans:bean>
```

and create html page in views folder, but after changes and try run i have this error:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/myapp/WEB-INF/views/home.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Why i have this error? I only change jsp to html.

Answer (score 2):

The `InternalResourceViewResolver`does not forward the request to the view folder. Instead it is responsible for selecting the 'jsp' (or what ever) according to the return value of an Controller(Method). Like

```
@RequestMapping("home")
public ModelAndView controllerMethodForHome(){
     //will render /WEB-INF/views/homeView.html
     return new ModelAndView("homeView");
}
```

with:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
   <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
   <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
</beans:bean>
```

will return the `/WEB-INF/views/homeView.html` for `localhost:8080/myApp/home`

---

Maybe the thing you want to use is the static resource mapping

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/resources/css/" />
```

Have a look at this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something) for an example