# How to serve Static pages in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I am developing an application with Spring MVC, What is the best way to serve the Static pages (fow which I don't need a Model and Controller). Since All the request go to dispatcher servlet first.

I understand that following tag will help to get my resources js,css and images from the resource directory.

```
<mvc:resources mapping="resources/**" location="resources/" />
```

But what if I have pages for eg (registration.jsp) that does not need a controller. Do I need to map every page using mvc:resources tag. If yes, will it be able to handle my tiles configuration?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC 3 and handling static content - am I missing something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something)

Comment: @Alex, I understand your point, can you please refer to the updated question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Static pages can be served same as the static resources

Keep your pages in some folder (say pages) under WEB-INF. and have this line in your dispatcher servlet

```
<mvc:resources mapping="pages/**" location="pages/" />
```