# Cannot find my css files in my html

Tags: css, html, spring

I have a spring controller which does a forward to a static html page index.html

The browser url display :

```
http://localhost:8080/app/type/static/name
```

Controller when gets this forwards:

```
return "forward:/static/pages/index.html";
```

The index page is located at:

```
webapp->static->pages->index.html
```

and the css is located at:

```
webapp->static->pages->css->style.css
```

when the url loads, it cant find the css file, looking in debugger

```
http://localhost:8080/app/type/static/pages/css/style.css
```

the url needs to be

```
http://localhost:8080/app/static/pages/css/style.css
```

I cant hard code this as the port can change? how can i do this?

Comment: some HTML code may help to find your problem.

Comment: Some good solutions to this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something

Answer (score 1):

appending this to href worked

../../

Answer (score 0):

Use in your head

```
<link href='css/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: no that doesnt work, it appends http://localhost:8080/app/type/static, how can get to the http://localhost:8080/app

Comment: Haha thought it said 'Use your head'

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/css/styles.css"/>">
```