# Spring Integration : How to add wadl(Restful service for JSON) contract to expose restful services like wsdl file

Tags: spring, rest, spring-integration, wadl

I want to expose project specific services as restful services(for JSON http request/response) that i exposed earlier for SOAP Request/Response type. Earlier we configured the static wsdl entries for SOAP using the

`web-services:static-wsdl id="MyWsdl" location="/WEB-INF/xsd/MyWsdl.wsdl"/>`

in the spring configuration files.

I need advice to know that Do we have ways to include my wadl contract files as we did for wsdl with the spring integration project or best way to expose my restful JSON service for the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply serve it up as a static resource from the WAR. See [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something) for howto.

Comment: This solved the problem. Appreciate your help.Thanks