# How do I serve resources when using my own handler mapping with Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my web application, pages are dynamically mapped to urls and pages can be added and removed. Hence, I wrote my own class extending `AbstractUrlHttpHandlerMapping` and all requests are routed to one handler method.

However, now I don't want resources to be treated the same way, resources should just be returned as usually. How do I achieve this? I tried returning a `ResourceHttpRequestHandler` for such resources, but I am not sure what to set `PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE` to. My attempts ended in an NPE.

Is there a better way to return resources while using my own handler mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised this is probably a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something). The solution presented there works for this case as well.