# Spring not recognizing image and css

Tags: java, spring, jsp

> Previous issue:

I created a webpage named `homepage.jsp` without the Spring application.
This page is supposed to be the regular website home page where you
can click to different sections like: *services*, *contact* and *news_blog*.
The `homepage.jsp` is in `WebContent`. It worked perfectly when the
application was created without the spring framework.

Now, because I incorporated spring since I would like to add a blog to
the *new_blog* section, the `homepage.jsp` can no longer see the image,
css and javascript.

I have searched the internet and tried several things but no progress
yet. This is what I have so far and I would appreciate your help
please. Thanks in advance.

[image: Application Structure]

I edited the Header from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/subsources/CSSFolder/stylesheet.css" /> 
<script src="resources/subsources/JavaScriptFolder/script.js"></script>
<script src="resources/subsources/JavaScriptFolder/crawler.js"></script>
```

> to this:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/resources/subsources/CSSFolder/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/resources/subsources/JavaScriptFolder/script.js"></script>
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/resources/subsources/JavaScriptFolder/crawler.js"
```

> I changed Part of the body from:

```
<div class="homepic">
   <img src="resources/subsources/images/Slide3.JPG" />
</div>
```

> to this:

```
<div class="homepic">
   <img id="homepic" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/resources/subsources/images/Slide3.JPG" >
</div>
```

> I added the following to my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>mvc-dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

> New Problem: The image is not showing up at all but everything
>   else is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **spring-config.xml** add this:

```
<mvc:resources location="/resources/subsources/" mapping="/resources/**"></mvc:resources>
```

and then in your **web.xml** have this:

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>dispatcher</display-name>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/spring-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: smoggers, I have a question to ask you. Is the header fine the way it is? The image now loads fine but the css is not showing up. Thanks

Comment: hmm that's interesting, is the JavaScript taking effect also? for the record this is how I load my css file within the <head> tags of my jsps: <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/main.css"
 rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> if both the css and js are not taking effect then try removing the 2 <servlet-mapping> in the web.xml  as images is not mapped and seems to be resolving fine without mapping

Comment: The Javascript is working fine, just the css. On my application, it's closed properly

Comment: can you try with <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/subsources/CSSFolder/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> ?? because I don't see why the .js and images would successfully be loaded and .css is not

Comment: It's working fine now with your suggestions. Let me just say that I removed the servlet mapping and added <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/subsources/CSSFolder/styleshe‌​et.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> like you suggested for it to start working fine. I have no idea why it would not work properly with the servlet-mapping. Any explanation? Thanks

Comment: I think this is to do with what version of spring you use but I'm not entirely sure. I use spring 3.2.3 and use both pageContext.request.contextPath and the servlet-mapping tags and works well

Comment: Ok, I will look into it more. Thanks

Comment: Hi smoggers, after looking into the last comment, I had to edit my code so that the jsps in the WebContent and in the pages worked together. Could you take a look at the new update I made to the question? Thanks

Comment: you changed to src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/resources/subsources/images/Slide3.JPG" but you don't have a folder named 'static' judging by your project structure ?

Comment: static was created as a path in web.xml. Other jsp files that I included in homepage.jsp picked it up along with the css that went with it. I tried it without "/static/" in <img> and it still did not pick it.

Comment: 'created as a path in web.xml' sorry I don't understand this statement. the 'pageContext.request' should replicate your project structure, you should be making sure the project structure matches this I'm not sure what you mean by modifying the web.xml

Comment: Kindly see this link: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something). I used the comment made by nickdos

Comment: he says 'The only change I made to JSPs was to add the /static/ path to URLs for CSS, JS and images. E.g. "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/css/screen.css".' so he has made this change because his folder structure is WebContent/static/css/screen.css. I've never used org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet that you are using now so I'm not sure how I can help now as you are using this with <servlet-name>ResourceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/static/*</url-pattern>. So fair enough I've helped you out in some ways but not provided a 100% solution

Comment: Adding static folder to match "/static/resources/subsources" did not work and also made the header section not to be recognized.

Comment: Your now using the resource servlet however whereas my projects only use the dispatcher servlet so hopefully someone else who uses the Resource servlet will be able to advise you

Comment: I've just been looking at that answer you linked to again and I'm not sure using ResourceServlet in the web.xml is ideal for your project. if you look at the documentation for org.springframework.js.resource.ResourceServlet it is actually meant to be used for javascript/ajax purposes, see here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/spring-js.html. I still think you should remove the ResourceServlet approach from web.xml and stick to <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/subsources/images/Slide3.JPG"/> using just the dispatcher servlet

Comment: I finally got it working. Your insistence on what path to take was what made me look through my code again. I did not use the resourceServlet anymore and also removed resources/subsources everywhere in my code. This actually gave me what I had been battling with for almost 1 week. Thank you so much.