# how to include js library on jsp page?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have Spring MVC project and on the JSP page I want to include js file from library:
[image: screen 1]
<sub>(source: [pastenow.ru](http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/E35L.jpg))</sub>

On the JSP page I added the following line:

```
<script src="resources/static/js/kurento-utils.js"></script>
```

but file is not found:

[image: enter link description here]
<sub>(source: [pastenow.ru](http://pastenow.ru/Upload/Paste/E362.jpg))</sub>

How to fix this?

Comment: Aren't you just missing a `/` before `resources`? Should be `<script src="/resources/st...`

Comment: It may also work when you add the path for script file from the location of JSP. For example if your jsp is also present in resources folder ignore the resources and use the path as <script src="static/js/kurento-utils.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Spring Tag Library](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.1/taglib/) to resolve the same, on your JSP page include the tag library and provide the folder path (where your js files are present) as value to `<spring:url>`, as follows:

**JSP Page:**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<spring:url value="/js/kurento-utils.js" var="kurentoUtils" />
<script src="${kurentoUtils}"></script>
</head>
```

In your Spring Configuration file add `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to load `*.js` files.

**springdispatcher-servlet.xml:**

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

And make sure your have **`spring-web`** and **`spring-webmvc`** dependencies in your `classpath`, mentioned below:

**pom.xml:**

```
<properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be available just by setting the src attribute to `/js/kurento-utils.js`, or is that only working with spring-boot?

Comment: It should, what I proposed is a standard way of including `.js` files using Spring.

Comment: Even if they get loaded through a Maven dependency?

Answer (score 0):

SpringMVC will serve whatever it finds in `resources/static/`, so the correct path should be `<script src="js/kurento-utils.js"></script>`.

You can also check in the [tutorials](https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-java/blob/master/kurento-hello-world/src/main/resources/static/index.html#L24), as we are using the same dependency.

If you want more info about how SpringMVC handles static resources, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something) other question might also help.

Comment: I have existing Spring MVC project that running on Jetty. Cat I integrate "kurento one2many call" with my project and run this on jetty ?

Comment: Yes, it shouldn't be hard. It's almost copy-paste, but with some care.