# How to serve an html file with .html url extension using Spring

Tags: spring, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use the Application Security on Cloud provided by Bluemix for a Spring application.

I'm relatively new to Spring and I'm having difficulty serving the requested verification file with the requested url. Bluemix wants the html file to be available at /IBMDomainVerification.html

However, I can't figure out how to serve the html file given that exact url using Spring. I can serve it without the .html at the end of the url but that's not what it needs.

If anyone can let me know how I can serve the html file given the specified url with the .html extension on the end that'd be great!

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?

Comment: I'm using Spring version 4.2.4

Answer (score 0):

Spring 4.1 introduced the *ResourceResolvers*, that can resolve resources, given their URL path. In particular you could use the simplest: *[PathResourceResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/PathResourceResolver.html)*. This is the simplest resolver and its purpose is to find a resource given a public URL pattern. In fact, if no ResourceResolver is added to the *[ResourceChainRegistration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ResourceChainRegistration.html)*, this is the default resolver.

Consider the following example:

```
@Override 
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
registry
  .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
  .addResourceLocations("/resources/","/other-resources/")
  .setCachePeriod(3600)
  .resourceChain(true)
  .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver());
}
```

The above code serves anything in either the webapp/resources of the webapp/other-resources folder, required with URLs /resources/** (e.g. */resources/foo.js*). Note the two asterisks, it means that it will match everything after *resources/*, even '/'.

In your case using /IBMDomainVerification.html (/**) it should work.

An alternative way could be using `*<mvc:resources/>*` (Spring 3)  which can be used to serve static resources while still using the DispatchServlet on root. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something) SO answer.