# How can I load an image from my resources/images folder in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to load 2 images from my resources/images folder and display them on my index.jsp:

```
<img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/harry_potter.jpg'/>"/>
<img alt="Image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/harry_potter.jpg">

<img src="<c:url value='/resources/images/hp.jpg'/>"/>
<img alt="Image" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/images/hp.jpg">
```

When I load the page images don't appear, instead there are image icons. As you've seen in my index.jsp, I've tried 2 different methods for loading an image

I have an application.xml page and a dispatcher-servlet page.xml

In each file I have tried putting this under the context:component-scan

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

but I still do not see my images on the index page. Does anyone know why this isn't showing

My File Structure for reference:
**File Image View**
[image: File Image View]

In my web.xml for reference:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Console for reference

**Console Image View**
[image: Console Image View]

Comment: Have you ever check what's the actual `src` value of your `img` tag?

Comment: @Reno I've edited the question with the console view which src value, which seems correct

Comment: Take a look of [Spring MVC 3 and handling static content - am I missing something?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/spring-mvc-3-and-handling-static-content-am-i-missing-something).

Comment: @Reno yeah I was following that question to add my images, and it doesn't seem to be working, I've done all that they've mentioned in the post

Comment: What about adding `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` to your `dispatcher-servlet page.xml`.

Comment: yeah I did, still no pics :(

Comment: What if change `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`?

Comment: @Reno The images are still not showing with the new url-pattern

Comment: Wow, this seems to be so weird, which spring version do you use?

Comment: yeah it's really weird, i'm using 4.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: OMG, I've be silly, your `resources` path is in `WEB-INF`, so you should change `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />` to `<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this please, may work;)

Change

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

to

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/WEB-INF/resources/" />
```

Comment: AHHH Thanks so much! Hours of headache, I actually tired to do img src = /WEB-INF/... directly in the jsp and it didn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just add `/WEB-INF/...` to your jsp didn't work because spring can dispatch your static resource request but can not find the resource in path which you've set in `location="/resources/"`.