# Spring MVC CSS and JS not loading

Tags: javascript, css, spring, model-view-controller, integration

Including floder structure

[image]I am developing a web application in Spring MVC. I have issues loading CSS and JS files in JSP.

I googled for hours and tried all options, but not succeeded.
Here is what i did

1. tried to load as normal web app giving relative path
2. tried including mvc:resources
3. tried loading through Resource Servlet even then nothing worked.

All three were tried separately
I am wondering what had i missed.

traditional link for #1

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

No changes done in mvc-config or web.xml

App Config for #2

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Web XML for #3

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.js.resource.ResouceServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

[image]

Comment: you miss ``<mvc:annotation-driven />`` ?

Comment: I have this in the xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this post helped me to resolve the issue.

[How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc)

But still wondering why my actions were not helpful