# Spring Boot unable to serve static image from resource folder

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application I have a following static file:

```
\src\main\resources\static\images\social\facebook\f_logo.jpg
```

This is my application.properties

```
server.port: 8080
server.contextPath: /api
```

I'm trying to access this file by the following url:

http://localhost:8080/api/images/social/facebook/f_logo.jpg

but the server returns `404 Not Found.`

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

My pom files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>example</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <jackson.version>2.8.0</jackson.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.boot.version>1.4.3.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <cdi-api.version>2.0-EDR1</cdi-api.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.18</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.6</logback.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
        <commons-validator.version>1.5.0</commons-validator.version>
        <commons-io.version>2.4</commons-io.version>

        <jacoco-maven-plugin.version>0.7.4.201502262128</jacoco-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.19</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <lifecycle-mapping.version>1.0.0</lifecycle-mapping.version>

        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-release-repository</id>
            <name>Neo4j Maven 2 release repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-libs-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <propertyName>jacoco.agent.argLine</propertyName>
                            <destFile>${jaCoCoExecutionDataFile}</destFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${jacoco.agent.argLine}</argLine>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>${lifecycle-mapping.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            jacoco-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [${jacoco-maven-plugin.version},)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore />
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jackson -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>${cdi-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jUnit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <modules>
        <module>domain</module>
        <module>api</module>
        <module>ui</module>
    </modules>
</project>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

        <neo4j.version>3.1.0</neo4j.version>
        <lucene.version>5.5.0</lucene.version>
        <spring-data-neo4j.version>4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data-neo4j.version>
        <neo4j-ogm.version>2.1.1-SNAPSHOT</neo4j-ogm.version>
        <spring-social-security.version>1.1.4.RELEASE</spring-social-security.version>
        <spring-security-oauth2.version>2.0.11.RELEASE</spring-security-oauth2.version>
        <hibernate-validator.version>5.2.4.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>neo4j-snapshot-repository</id>
            <name>Neo4j Maven 2 snapshot repository</name>
            <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <optimize>true</optimize>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- neo4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-core</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-http-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-embedded-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j-ogm.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j-enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>neo4j-security-enterprise</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-data-neo4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-social-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-oauth2.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Lucene -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>19.0-rc1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <parent>
        <artifactId>example</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <!-- example -->
        <com.example.domain.version>0.0.1</com.example.domain.version>
        <!-- 3rd party -->
        <spring-security-core.version>4.1.3.RELEASE</spring-security-core.version>
        <spring.social.google.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</spring.social.google.version>
        <spring-social-github.version>1.0.0.M4</spring-social-github.version>
        <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
        <javaee-web-api.version>7.0</javaee-web-api.version>
        <json-path.version>2.0.0</json-path.version>
        <rest-assured.version>2.8.0</rest-assured.version>
        <httpclient>4.5.2</httpclient>
        <springfox-swagger2.version>2.6.0</springfox-swagger2.version>
        <gson.version>2.6.2</gson.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.3</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-war-plugin.version>2.6</maven-war-plugin.version>
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- example -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>domain</artifactId>
            <version>${com.example.domain.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Social Providers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Social Providers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.social.google.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-github</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-social-github.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>${json-path.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>${json-path.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- default j2ee dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee-web-api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger2 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springfox-swagger2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <addResources>false</addResources>
                    <jvmArguments>
                        -Xdebug
                        -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
                    </jvmArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Just reproduce exact the same in a simple project and I am able to see my image. Maybe any typo? If not you have to share more infos.

Comment: Not a typo because it is working with a solution provided by @gipple lake below

Comment: OK. Can you provide your pom.

Comment: I think the problem is that you use Spring-web and spring-webmvc dependency and not the spring boot related one. What is if you use `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: I have completely removed Spring-web and spring-webmvc but the issue is not gone

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry）{ 
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                 .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Maybe you have added `@EnableWebMvc` which looks for handlers  corresponding to `/api/images/social/facebook/f_logo.jpg`.
Just remove that & provide WebMvcConfigurer or WebMvcConfigurationSupport similar to what I have posted.

Comment: its a spring boot app. Normally there is no need to configure resourcehandlers manually

Comment: Thanks, It is working ! But I agree with @Patrick - this is a Spring Boot and AFAIK - it should work by default. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Adding this configuration file works, but i've got a question. One of my images could be found without it but all others need this particular configuration. Can someone helps understand why !

Comment: How is anyone seeing this answer supposed to know which file to put this code in? Or how to get the framework to pick up that file? Come on.

Comment: It's public java class so you don't have too much choice but to put in in file WebConfiguration.java. Framework will pick it up due to `@Configuration` annotation

Comment: yes, I have issue with @EnableWebMvc

Answer (score 13):

Same problem with me. (Spring Boot 2)

I resolve below.

**Step 1**: Move `images` folder from `src/main/resources/static/images` to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/images`

**Step 2**: Look up `SpringBootMainApplication.java` add code

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    // Register resource handler for images
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
}
```

**Step 3**: Run program and go to browser `http://localhost:8080/images/logo.png`

If your set contextRoot `http://localhost:8080/project/images/logo.png`

**Full Code**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApplication.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        // Register resource handler for images
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/images/")
                .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Work for me.

---

**Additional**

Or you can set below, If you want using in resources folder.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/statics/")
            .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
}
```

Because after deploy project structure below.

[image]

`http://localhost:8080/images/logo.png`

or

`http://localhost:8080/project/images/logo.png`

Sorry for English.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me. :)

Comment: You shouldn't move resources out of recources. And there's no Web-Inf

Answer (score 6):

in your application properties file set the following line :

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:///c:/{yourWorkSpace}/{projectName}/src/main/resources/static/
```

this is tested.

Comment: Worked thank you. Do you know why we need to do this? Is it maybe because we did the setup incorrectly or is it a problem with spring boot not being able to see the path?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a clean solution to serve from resources folder. Tested on Spring Boot v2.1.4.RELEASE. 
[image]

```
    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {      
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/","classpath:/image/")
            .setCachePeriod(0);
        }
    }
```

You can make this a nested class of Application (or whichever class of yours extends SpringBootServletInitializer). You can declare many folders like

> .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/","classpath:/image/","classpath:/largeimage/","classpath:/pdf/")

Make sure src/main/resources is a source folder, and the folders you specify are directly under it.

Then you can simply display images like this in your html or jsp files.

```
<img src="ok.png"/>
```

Comment: You can build an excellent and maintable UI using Java/HTML/CSS/JS. Tools like React add to many unhelpful abstractions and overcomplicate the front end. Don't be afraid to use SpringBoot for your UI!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your images in path which you have given \src\main\resources\static\images\social\facebook\f_logo.jpg and while loading images in JSP, give relative path to resources/static like this src="/images/social/facebook/f_logo.jpg". This will load the image.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of http://localhost:8080/api/images/social/facebook/f_logo.jpg,

try this
http://localhost:8080/images/social/facebook/f_logo.jpg

It should work as the default path starts from /, not /api

Answer (score -1):

After some research and reproduce I can confirm that your provided resource path and your link is correct.

In your `pom.xml` you have many "not Spring-boot related" dependencies. If you want to go further with this configuration, you need to follow [gipple lake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41691974/3493036) because you are not using the autoconfiguration of spring-boot-web.

But if you want to get to out of the box solution I would suggest to replace the Spring core dependencies with the Spring-boot related ones.

For example use:

```
<dependency> 
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

instead of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Maybe you should also add the boot starter dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Adding a bunch of dependencies is not an answer to the question.

Comment: @AndrewKoster have you even read the full answer? Seems that you dont understand that this is a suggestion to switch to Spring-boot components to use an out of the box solution. Please make sure, that your comments are helpful in future

Comment: You're suggesting that people swap out their dependencies, without explaining: 1) why 2) how this affects the code or 3) how this affects the behavior of the web app. It's a very confusing answer, no matter how many times I re-read it.

Answer (score -1):

*I have faced same issue while running spring boot application using apache tomcate 9.0.
rightnow resolved the same.
1. i have added validation.properties file in my app. folder structure looking like below,
   --src/main/resources
   --static
   --application.properties
   --validations.properties
2. next i have moves images,css and js folder under src/main/webapp folder.
3. next i have done below three steps,
   --cleaned project 
   --maven install
   --update project
4. finally ran application ,it was working successfully.*

Comment: what?
also, what

Answer (score -2):

Can you show us your configuration files?

You got `404` when the url is not mapped, please provide us the controller.

Also you might have a look at: [How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc) and http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources (tutorial)

Comment: getting down vote because asking for code, so i can hep you, thank you

Comment: You shared links which are not spring-boot related. If you use spring-boot you should NOT do the stuff you provided in the links.

Comment: so in my linked tutorial you could also find gipple answer, is MVC configuration related to spring boot, no? but does it work? seems it is, nevermind, this question got an answer, have a nice day

Comment: Did you even read the articles that you posted? They say things like "Serving static files to the client can be done in a variety of ways, and using a Spring Controller isn't necessarily the best available option.

However, sometimes the controller route is necessary – and that's what we're going to be focused on in this quick article."

Comment: Obviously, in any sane web development environment, you shouldn't need to write an entire controller just to serve one static file. That's insane and not a practical solution.