# Java Spring with mustache keeps looking for files on server

Tags: java, spring, web, mustache

I've been trying to develop a quick website using Java Spring with Mustache for templating but I have an issue when it comes to getting local files (css stylesheets or images). I'm running the website on intelliJ on http://localhost:8000 and for some reason it looks for every files on http://localhost:8000/Path/to/the/file and returns a 404 error on the inspector (no error in the console log)

Here are my file-tree and the code I'm using. The templates .mustache are in the templates directory.

[image: filetree]

```
<nav class="level">
    <div class="level-left">
        <div class="level-item">
            <img src="/img/flags/gb.svg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="level-item">
            <img src="/img/flags/fr.svg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="level-item">
            <img src="/img/flags/es.jpg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="level-item">
            <img src="/img/flags/ch.svg"/>
        </div>
        <div class="level-item">
            <img src="/img/flags/de.svg"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I saw some posts telling to add a resource handler like this :

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/css");
registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/img");
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
```

But no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you try adding static before your path, something like this   `<img src="/static/img/flags/de.svg"/>`

Comment: I already tried that it just adds a `No mapping for GET /static/img/flags/fr.svg` in the console

Comment: in your configuration `public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/resources/"); 
    }` and access it like `<img src="/resources/static/img/flags/de.svg"/>`

Comment: Just tried it, does like `/img/flags/de.svg` returns a 404 but does'nt log in the console

Comment: tried like `<img src="/resources/static/img/flags/de.svg"/>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this resource handler for your static resources

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
```

If it doesn't work you can check furher here - [Spring Boot unabe to serve static image from resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691770/spring-boot-unabe-to-serve-static-image-from-resource-folder)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you :)