# Where to put image in Java project for it to be rendered in index.html

Tags: java, html, image

I have got a spring boot project with a simple `html` page where i render my data.

I want to add an image to the html, but when I run application the image is not rendered, no matter where in project I put it to.

Is there a special place, you should put it to?

Currently my `index.html` is in `src/resources/templates`.

Comment: If you use thymeleaf check this link [Images in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460618/inserting-an-image-from-local-directory-in-thymeleaf-spring-framework-with-mave)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot unabe to serve static image from resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691770/spring-boot-unabe-to-serve-static-image-from-resource-folder)