# Display image from resources folder in spring boot and vue js

Tags: java, spring-boot, vue.js

I'm trying to build a function of uploading image to images folder inside resources with directory:

*resources/static/images/imagesName.jpg*

Here is the code for this function:

```
public String Redirection(String Parameter, MultipartFile sourceFile, Integer VID) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException{

// upload image into resources

byte[] bytes = sourceFile.getBytes();
String fileType = sourceFile.getOriginalFilename();
String[] parts = fileType.split(Pattern.quote("."));
String part1 = parts[0]; 
String part2 = parts[1];

String fileLocation = new File("src\\main\\resources\\static\\images").getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + VID + "." + part2;
System.out.println(fileLocation);
Path path = Paths.get(fileLocation);
Files.write(path, bytes);
}
```

For this part, it's working fine. However, when I try to retrieve the image on front end which is on vue, I'm stuck with how it's supposed to work. I tried to refer to this one answered by Bamossza

[Spring Boot unable to serve static image from resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691770/spring-boot-unable-to-serve-static-image-from-resource-folder/41691974#41691974)

which I add configuration on my main application as follows:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {      
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
        .setCacheControl(CacheControl.maxAge(2, TimeUnit.HOURS).cachePublic());
    }
}
```

And on the front end which is on Vue.js, I retrieve the image by doing

```
<CImg src="/images/141.png" shape="rounded"></CImg>
```

The image should be dynamic but for now, I'm just trying to make it display first but it doesn't show anything. Is there any solution to make it work? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is 'CImg' ? Can you retrieve the image by fetching it by it's full url?

Comment: CImg is the tag similar to <img>. I'm using coreui and refer to their documentation here (https://coreui.io/react/docs/3.3/components/CImg/) I tried to fetch it like this _<CImg src="C:/Users/User/Desktop/ana/Task2/morefolderhere/resources/static/images/183.png" shape="rounded"></CImg>_ but it return this error at console **Not allowed to load local resource:**

Comment: I ment fetch by its full url, not the location on the operating system (that is not public visible). For example http://localhost//resources/static/images/183.png.