# Spring boot serve static images from outside folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

i got this project structure :

- api

  ```
     src/main/java
         -some classes
     reports /
         -screenshots
             - imageOne.png
  ```

i want to serve the imageOne.png like this localhost:8080/imageOne.png

i got this configuration

```
@Configuration
public class Configurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Configurer.class);
    private final String RESOURCE_LOCATION = "file:/api/reports/screenshots";
    private final String ANT_PATH_EXPRESSION="/**";
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
 
        registry
                .addResourceHandler(ANT_PATH_EXPRESSION)
                .addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATION);

        
    }
/**
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    
        return builder.sources(ApiRestApplication.class);
    }
    */

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
 
        registry.addMapping("/**");
        
    }
```

but is not working and everytime i do localhost:8080/imageOne.png is returning:

```
        There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

i need help to find where i mess up in the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot unable to serve static image from resource folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691770/spring-boot-unable-to-serve-static-image-from-resource-folder)

Comment: no , i was reading that before making this  post but still it didnt work

Comment: In the above link/answer,the path to the resource folder is prefixed with `classpath:` - in your code above is prefixed with `file:` - why are you using `file:` ?

Comment: because is external folder, like is outside src

Comment: And what is this `/api` prefix doing?

Comment: is the parent folder, api main folder inside api we got reports folder and inside reports we got screenshots folder with images also inside api we got src/main/java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was able to solve it by adding  the folder to the buildpath in maven using ${basedir}/reports/screenshots to make it relative instead of static i tested it using different operative system. Here is the "code"

```
<build>
        <finalName>somename</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>

            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/reports</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

and adding this on the application.properties

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/
```

and this is the custom configuration

```
 //private final String RESOURCE_LOCATION = "classpath:/";
    private final String ANT_PATH_EXPRESSION="reports/**";
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  
        registry 
                .addResourceHandler(ANT_PATH_EXPRESSION)  ;
                //.addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATION);
       
    }
```