# Not able to refer JavaScript from outside file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am new to Spring and JavaScript.

I have created a JSP file [image]

In my first.js ,I have the following method

```
function firstmethod()
{
    window.alert("Enter a New Number");
    return true;
}
```

But the javascript method is not getting executed.I couldn't figure out the reason.Please suggest

The browser console error log is

[image]

Console Error log

[image]

Comment: Can you just share your browser console error log ?

Comment: @Ravi i have updated the Screenshot of it

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc

Answer (score 0):

I would first check to see if the file is showing up in your web browser correctly:

Right-click in browser window, choose "View Page Source (if you're using chrome)," navigate to the  tag, find the link to your javascript file and click on it. You should see the contents of it display in your window.

If the code looks right, you might have an error in it. The browser developer tools (right-click browser window, select "Inspect Element") will sometimes display those errors in the "Console" tab.

The code seems fine. Here's a snippet for it:

```js
function firstmethod()
{
    alert("Enter a New Number");
    return true;
}
```

```html
<form name="firstform" method="post" action="first" onsubmit="return firstmethod()">
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Click" />
</form>
```