# Spring boot resource static folder

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Shortly I have application which is structered as below and the problem is that spring boot not scanning static folder recursively. I mean 
if i put bootstrap.min.css to `static/css/bootstrap.min.css` it is okay no problem but if i put into another folder in subpackage of static folder `static/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css` , just like in the screenshot then I am not able load these resources. How can I handle this ? Thanks in advance.  [image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc -this may help

Answer (score 2):

Your URL lacks a leading slash.

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls

> There are different types of URLs:
>
> - Absolute URLs: http://www.thymeleaf.org
> - Relative URLs, which can be:
>
>   - Page-relative: user/login.html
>   - Context-relative: /itemdetails?id=3 (context name in server will be added automatically)
>   - Server-relative: ~/billing/processInvoice (allows calling URLs in another context (= application) in the same server.
>   - Protocol-relative URLs: //code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js

The URL in your screenshot, *bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css*, is page-relative.

What you want is a context-relative URL. When your file is in *src/main/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css*, use:

```
th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
```

When it's in in *src/main/resources/static/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css*, use:

```
th:href="@{/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css}"
```

Furthermore, instead of manually downloading bootstrap.min.css, I suggest you use the [Bootstrap WebJar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6) and then use the following href:

```
th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
```