# Spring MVC doesn't load css, js files to static html pages

Tags: java, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

I disabled the role of the **InternalViewResolver** in order to access some static pages, **html** not **jsp** pages, i made the required changed, indeed i made and i can access my html page, but when i see the browser's console it looks like it didn't bring my local **css** and **js** files.

[image: Output 1 of the request]

This is my project structure.

[image: Project structure]

This is my header page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>ECommerce view example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/login.css"/>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBR8P_sULnn-egsyhOb6qLYG2oqFshTiwY"></script>
</head>
```

**mvc-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <annotation-driven></annotation-driven>
        <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
        <context:component-scan base-package="ma.s2m.net"></context:component-scan>         
        <resources mapping="/static/**" location="/WEB-INF/static/"></resources>
    </beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the browser console, it seems your path is invalid.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css"/>`

resolved to URL:
`http://localhost:8080/static/css/style.css`.

Context root in URL is missing here. Ideally URL should have been something like this.
`http://localhost:8080/<CONTEXT_ROOT>/static/css/style.css`

In your case, as this is static html page, only one correction is required to match the URI with webapp directory.

Make following changes in `entry.html` and it would work.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/login.css"/>`

Hope it solves your error.

Comment: it didn't work, i don't know it is so ambiguous like this, i tried all the possible combinations between `mvc-config .xml` and `entry.html` css locations.

Comment: can you paste the browser console snapshot here again please.

Comment: This is the update `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css"/>`, this is console snapshot `http://localhost:8080/ssytem-ecommerce-prototype-view/css/style.css` **404 not found**

Comment: Can you please try with this line. I will modify the answer if it works.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/style.css"/>`

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/ssytem-ecommerce-prototype-view/css/login.css` **404 not found**, it's like it doesn't recognize the root path

Comment: one more change.
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/login.css"/>`

Comment: No i picked one of the 3 **404 not found** messages, that was only the a snapshot of the full missing resources error logged by the navigator.

Comment: I'm afraid that with no `InternalViewResolver` and with no `jsp` pages, it's not possible to load the resources.

Comment: Its not the case. If you can upload the code base to some git repo. I can have a look and help to solve

Answer (score 1):

We generally keep the css,js inside resource folder and the hierarchy is as follows:

```
webapp
  resource
    static
      css
        style.css
      js
        ...
  WEB-INF
    ...
```

Try with above hierarchy. Change resource-mapping to

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/static/"></resources>.
```

Comment: It returns `404 not found` on the entire page, not just the resources.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the  tag to resolve your static css & js. You can refer [How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: it doesn't change anything. i wanna have an access with no helpers, nothing, no jstl, nothing. exactly like what we do in a spring boot application.

Comment: your stylesheet links will resolve to webapp/static/css/ directory. As the files are not present in that directory you are getting a 404 error. If you are using a resources tag then you will need to take help of JSTL or spring tag. Another option is to ignore the resource tag and give paths as we give in a static html page. For that all your files should be below the webapp directory as files under WEB-INF folder are secure and can't be directly accessed by a browser client.

Comment: it didn't work, i adopted the second option, i replaced my resources under webapp folder, this is the link **<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/style.css"/>**

Comment: Try moving the entire contents of static folder along with the entry.html file under webapp directory &  use  **<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>**

Comment: Still nothing, i did what you told me

Answer (score 0):

just noticed remove the **/** from href attribute the will solve this issue.

please try change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/login.css"/>
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/login.css"/>
```

hope can help you.