# spring mvc can not mapping resources(eg. html) with no constraint

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm learning easyui on java web project.

And I can't open the url

`http://localhost:1234/learn/webpage/jquery-easyui-1.5.2/datagrid/basic.html`

The error:

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
>           warning: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/learn/webpage/jquery-easyui-1.5.2/datagrid/basic.html] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringMVC'

Comment: How to serve static resources is described in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-static-resources

Comment: [the answer in stack of flower](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4367280/8243662)