# how to navigate from one page to another in spring framework without calling the controller each time

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-mvc, oracle12c

We have multiple pages in a web application.I am using spring framework with java and angularjs ..I am not able to understand how to navigate from one page to another without calling the controller each time..Can anyone help?

Comment: That's the whole purpose of the controller.  why would you want that?

Comment: You should deal with static content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc

Comment: I am including js file (containing controller implementation stuff) in html file using script tag ...it isnt working ..i dont understand why...i went through the article above for including static resources but didnt work for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
// Code goes here
Below code may help you to redirect you from one page to another page.

(function () {
  'use strict';


  function LoginController($scope, $log, $location, $http) {

    //onSuccess callback....
    function onLoginSuccess(res) {
        $log.info('Successfully logged in.');
        $location.path(NavigationPath.HOME);
    }

    //onError callback
    function onError(error) {
      $log.error('Login in failed.', error);
    }

    /**
     * Sign in user after validating the credentials.
     */
    $scope.signIn = function () {
      $scope.isSigningIn = true;
      var formData = {
        username: $scope.userName,
        password: $scope.password
      };
      $http.post(formData).then(onLoginSuccess, onError).finally(function () {
        //final stuff you can do here
      });
    };
    onLoad();
  }


  var app = angular.module('app'),
      requires = [
        '$scope',
        '$log',
        '$location',
        '$http',
        LoginController
      ];
  app.controller('LoginController', requires);

}());
```

Comment: I am separating the code in two parts such that all the controller stuff is inside js file and then including this js file in the html file using the script tag...but it doesnt seems to be working