# How to Map a URI to a single file and render it in spring MVC?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

In spring MVC, 
Please let me know how can I render a static file using just a URI. I want to map a uri i.e. http://example.com/xyz where XYZ is a URI(without file extention) to 
a file

I want to achieve something like this below but this is not working.Please help

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/apple-app-association-file" location="/content/applejson/apple-app-association-file.json" />
```

and access json by http://example.com/apple-app-association-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle static content in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: I am looking for a way to access a file on the server without the file extension.