# Spring mvc not loading css and images

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

When I start the app in browser it loads only html text and not the css and images. How can I fix it ?

This is my MvcConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .setCachePeriod(0);

    registry.addResourceHandler("/static/imag/**").addResourceLocations("/static/imag/**");
}


public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {

    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("beers");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");

}

@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**");
}
}
```

And here is my project structure:

[project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWwhL.png)

Also I have in application.properties this code:

```
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

And here is my controller:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@Controller
public class HomeController {


@GetMapping("/")
public String home(){
    return  "index";
}

@GetMapping("/login")
public String login(){
    return  "login";
}
}
```

Comment: I think this post will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483063/how-to-handle-static-content-in-spring-mvc

Comment: From Spring 3, all the resources needs to mapped in a different way. You need to use the tag to specify the location of the resources.

Comment: I tried these ways too, but it didn't help.

Comment: What is the src that you gave your js and css files in html? `js/filename.js` or directly `filename.js` ?